# Error launching chrome on Ubuntu WSL: Failed to connect to the bus, Missing X server or DISPLAY

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, wsl2

I've installed chrome on my wsl ubuntu by following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps).

When I launch Chrome I get an error as below. I've tried both with and without `DISPLAY`.

```
(base) me@USC-W-C6GLQG3: google-chrome

[21122:21149:0905/122347.373828:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[21122:21122:0905/122347.376372:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[21122:21122:0905/122347.376392:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
(base) me@USC-W-C6GLQG3:/tmp$ echo $DISPLAY
172.26.32.1:0
```